# touchpad stops working on lenovo helix2 with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Helix 2 and I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on it. Most of the time after a while that I don't use touchpad, it  stops working and I have to use external mouse or screen touch. only reboot fix it.
how can I fix the problem?